# Meaning of this code (probably in FORTRAN 90)

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I found following code in one of the frameworks we are using:

```
Rem = max (50.0, gm*diamj(i)/vism)
```

I am looking for the result of Rem. The gm, diamj, vism should be other formula or alphanumeric name.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. It is often necessary to show more code. We normaly need to know where does each of the names in your line come from. Otherwise, for exsmple, `diamj` can be an array or a function.

Answer (score 2):

It's fairly straightforward: it just calculates `Rem` from a simple formula, and then uses `max` to limit the result to a value of at least 50, i.e.

```
Rem = gm*diamj(i)/vism
if (Rem < 50.0)
    Rem = 50.0
```

Comment: This largely assumes that `max` is a particular function.  It may not be and it isn't possible to tell from the code presented in the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49851170/3157076) which gives a plausible idea of what the line in the question means.  However, an important thing to understand is that it isn't generally possible to isolate the individual lines of code without further context.

That is, from just this single line **you cannot tell what will happen**.

While there is an intrinsic function `max` which returns the maximum value of the two arguments we do not know that this function is being used.

Consider the case

```
function max(a,b)
   intrinsic min
   max = min(a,b)
end function max

external max
Rem = max(1., 2.)
print*, Rem
end
```

Here an external function called `max` is used, not the intrinsic.

There's also

```
type max
  real a,b
end type
type(max) Rem
Rem = max(1., 2.)
print*, Rem
end
```

Here the default structure constructor for a derived type called `max` is used.  `max` may even be a generic, or feature other such excitement.

Now, even if `max` is the intrinsic function, we don't understand the second argument in the question: `diamj` could be an array or a function.  See

```
function diamj(i)
  error stop
end function

Rem = max(1.,diamj(2))
print*, Rem
end
```

---

What we can safely say is that `max` isn't an array.  However, there's

```
integer :: max(2,2)=-1
Rem = max(1,2)
print*, Rem
end
```

which is very different from

```
Rem = max(1,2)
print*, Rem
end
```

---

Arguably you shouldn't do any of these things but you also shouldn't assume other people haven't.